# return a groups event using the c# microsoft graph sdk

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am a bit new to microsoft graph api.
I am attempting to get all events for an office 365 group
I successfully got the results back microsoft graph explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

using the query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/88d59881-7b15-4adc-a756-5d10681cf99d/events

however I can't quite figure out how to do the same using the c# sdk.  I can get the group information but I don't know how to get the array of events.

here is how I get the group information.  but I'm unsure how to add in the events I now  in ef core it would be `groups.include(x => x.events)` but that doesn't seem to work using microsoft graph sdk.

```
public  static Task<Group> GetGroup()
{
    EnsureGraphForAppOnlyAuth();
    // Ensure client isn't null
    _ = _appClient ??
        throw new System.NullReferenceException("Graph has not been initialized for app-only auth");

    return _appClient.Groups["88d59881-7b15-4adc-a756-5d10681cf99d"]
        .Request()
        .Select(u => new
        {
            // Only request specific properties
            u.DisplayName,
            u.Id,
            u.Description
        })
        .GetAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph API Explorer has a tab `Code snippets` where you can find how to rewrite the query by using SDK for selected language.

[image]

Comment: thanks did not see that.  of course my next problem is I want to use the application credentials (app secret) and not have the user log in and it appears events does not support that authentication but I guess that will be a separate question

Answer (score 2):

```cs
var groupEvents = await _appClient.Groups[""].Events.Request().GetAsync();
```